# Unit testing in rails using factory_girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, factory-bot

I am trying to unit test a method inside a model as shown below in rails. The whole aim is to do a database independent testing here and so thinking of using Factory girl.

For eg.,

```
Class A < ActiveRecord::Base 
       def self.method_A(param1,param2) do
         /*do a select query on a table with param1 and param2*/
       end
```

end

How to go about testing the method here with arguments here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I figured it out.. build a list and then mock a call on the class method like this                                                                                                       **bold** `allow(A).to receive(:methodA).with(param1,param2).and_return(constructed_list)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah that looks correct. You kind of mock the class method and assert it